# How to press the keyboard to select the List<slot> and after that, right click on mouse to do action

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have already do script to press and then take an action. but my customer wants me to press key just to select slot[i] and then right click on mouse for taking an action... Like star dew game (sigh).

```
for (int i = 0; i < ItemSlots.Length; i++)
        {


        if (Input.GetKeyUp(ItemSlots[i].keyCode))
        {
            invManager.RightClickorPresstoUse(ItemSlots[i]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your code currently says "for each hotbar slot: get the item in the main inventory in the same index: if the key is pressed for that slot: do right click." I am pretty sure there are two problems here, but you haven't said what they are. (1) you're not selecting the hotbar slot and (2) you're checking the wrong inventory (`inv.ItemSlots[i]` should probably be `hotBarSlots[i]`).

Comment: as I informed, I have already done this perfectly if I just only pressed and took action. but customer wants more

Comment: ok I edited for making you understand easily.

Comment: So...what does not function correctly?

Comment: 1. want to press key to select slot (just collect int )
2. after selecting slot, anytime when i want to use that slot, i have to right click on mouse

that's not surprising that you confused, me as well..

Comment: You don't have any code to say that the slot is selected. We can't write that for you, you need to write that.